# Angular Js ng-repeat can't getting output from json array using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, ajax

I am using Angular Js having ajax but by using ng-repeat can't getting output from json array. On alert getting [Object object]...so on but by using `$scope.names= response[0].id;` , getting "1" id on alert. I need to get all data in table. Is there any way to get all data in table and also I am not using `$http` in controller because it not working in mobile browser but works in desktop, i don't know why?Please help!

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('studentApp',[]);
app.controller('StudentCntrl', function($scope){

$.ajax({
    url : '/fetchAllData',
    type : 'GET',
    success : function(response){
        $scope.names=response;
        //alert($scope.names);(This is working)
          } 
     });
});
```

**JSP**

```
<div ng-app="studentApp" ng-controller="StudentCntrl">

      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>NAME</th>
              <th>EMAIL</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
              <td>{{x.id}}</td>
              <td>{{x.name}}</td>
              <td>{{x.email}}</td>

            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
```

**Json**

```
[{"id":"1","name":"abdul","email":"a@gmail.com"},{"id":"2","name":"pratyush","email":"p@gmail.com"},{"id":"3","name":"ankit","email":"a@gmail.com"},{"id":"45","name":"kjhj","email":"kjhkj"},{"id":null,"name":null,"email":null},{"id":null,"name":null,"email":null},{"id":null,"name":null,"email":null},{"id":"trffs","name":null,"email":null},{"id":"afa","name":"sdgfdsg","email":"dsagdsg"},{"id":"12","name":"pppp","email":"hjk,gh"}]
```

Comment: Don't use jQuery, inject `$http`

Comment: I tried that first but not working in mobile browser.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Which angular version, and browser type and version? As mentioned by others, it should work in mobile if $http is used correctly.

Comment: wat errors you have?

Comment: Actually I am verifying my project on mobile browser using my system ip, Is this is the reason its not working on mobile(data not showing in table)? Like 198.0.X.X:8080/home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When updating the scope with an $ajax call (you should use $http), you have to use $scope apply to update your bindings.

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.names = response.data;
});
```

Comment: Can you explain with a example?

Comment: I've build you a small example, with jQuery and $scope.$apply in the .done function. I prefer to use .done and .fail as this uses the returned promise object.
http://codepen.io/robbert/pen/rrLQgq/

Comment: Thank you very much, its working on both desktop and mobile browser..!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of ajax call , use [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) with angular as below

```
var app = angular.module('studentApp', []);
app.controller('StudentCntrl', function($scope,$http) {
    $http.get('data.json').then(function (response){
                  console.log(response.data.pages);
                $scope.names = response.data;
        });
});
```

Here is the working **[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/JwpnWAZYPiRcakJJE8t3?p=preview)**

Comment: I tried that first, it was not working in mobile browser there was some issue in spring config, so i was trying this method.

Comment: if you are using angular this is the way and it should work with mobile as well

Comment: Actually I am verifying my project on mobile browser using my system ip, Is this is the reason its not working on mobile? Like 198.0.X.X:8080/home